# Setting dataprovider in Combobox freezes the UI

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, combobox, flex3

I am using a Combobox component for a category dropdown in my application. But on loading the page, if I click on the category dropdown the UI freezes. There are no errors in the console. I have this code in my commit properties.

```
          if (_categoriesChanged)
            {
                _categoriesChanged = false;
                categoryCombo.dataProvider = categories;//If i comment out this line, everything works normal
                setSelectedCategory();
            }
```

I have similar usage of combobox elsewhere in the application and I have no issues. 
Also this doesn't happen if I put a breakpoint and go step by step (hence can't debug too).

Anyone with any idea?

Comment: Where the categories comes from?

Comment: Very likely you enter an infinite loop resetting and resetting again the data.

Comment: Well, when I debug, i see that the _categories variable is set properly and has all the elements, and the whole application flow is perfect. The issue is not reproduced either (except at times). But when I run it normally it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you add a bit more code?  Botmaster is probably right about an infinite loop, but it's impossible to tell from the snippet you've provided.